# Problems with rows in ListView

Tags: android

Good day, please kindly help me review this code and tell me what i am doing wrong. My listview is not returning the correct row position. it keeps giving me the previous row entry and not the one clicked and it gives me the error "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0" when i try to click on the first entry in the list.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ViewItems extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

 DBAdapter adapter;
 Cursor cursor;
 ListView list;
 static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 0;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.view_list);
  adapter = new DBAdapter(this);
  adapter.open();
  fillData();

  list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  list.setOnItemClickListener(this);


 }


 protected void fillData() {
  Cursor cursor = adapter.retrieveItems();
  startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.NAME, DBAdapter.DATE, DBAdapter.TIME};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.viewNameId, R.id.viewDateId, R.id.viewTimeId};

    customCursorAdapter items = new customCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.view_items, cursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(items);   
 }



 public class customCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
  private int layout;
  Context context;

  public customCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[]from, int[] to) {
   super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
   this.layout = layout;
   this.context = context;

  }


  @Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
   ViewHolder holder;

   if(view != null){
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.viewName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.viewNameId);
    holder.viewStartDate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.viewDateId);
    holder.viewStartTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.viewTimeId);

    view.setTag(holder);
   }else{
    holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
   }

   int namecol = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.NAME); 
   String name = cursor.getString(namecol);


   if(holder.viewName != null){
   holder.viewName.setText(name);
   holder.viewName.setTextColor(Color.RED);
   }

   String startDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.DATE));
   holder.viewStartDate.setText(startDate);

   String startTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.TIME));
   holder.viewStartTime.setText(startTime);
  }


  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   final View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

   return view;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int id){
   return id;
  }

 @Override
  public Object getItem(int position){
   return position;
  }

 }

 static class ViewHolder{
  TextView viewName;
  TextView viewStartDate;
  TextView viewStartTime;

 }


 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {

   cursor = adapter.retrieveRow(rowId);

  Intent edit = new Intent(this,AddItem.class);
   edit.putExtra(DBAdapter.KEY_ID, rowId);
   edit.putExtra(DBAdapter.NAME, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.NAME)));
   edit.putExtra(DBAdapter.DATE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.DATE)));
   edit.putExtra(DBAdapter.TIME, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.TIME)));
   startActivityForResult(edit, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
 }

 }
```

I have tried and reviewed examples but no success. I have also tried to use OnListItemClick() method but that gives me a "NullPointerException", i don't know why. Its been so frustrating for some time now. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you sure you are returning the right ID on the `getItemId` method? I saw you are returning the **position** not the ID of the row, which are probably different.

Comment: sorry am not really sure what you mean since i have the two methods there. i should guess i am returning the right ID of the rows, because the columns entries seem to correlate with it. as i say, my problem is when i click on an item, the one above it is returned and not the clicked on. if i missed your point, please let me know.

Comment: seem to have solved the problem. i just deleted the database and re-installed the application and everything is working fine. still can't understand why anyway?